# assignment from incompatible pointer type (struct) c

Tags: pointers, struct, gtk

for the struct

```
typedef struct Recording_Settings recording_settings;
struct Recording_Settings
{
    gchar *profile;
    gchar *destination;
};

recording_settings rec_settings;
```

I get a warning when I try to do this

```
static void profile_combo_change_cb(GtkComboBox *combo, gpointer userdata)
{
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreeModel *model;

    /* Grab the encoding profile choosen */
    model = gtk_combo_box_get_model (GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo));
    if (gtk_combo_box_get_active_iter(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), &iter)) {
        gchar *media_type;
        gtk_tree_model_get(GTK_TREE_MODEL(model), &iter, 0, &media_type, -1);
        rec_settings.profile = rb_gst_get_encoding_profile(media_type); // Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
        g_free (media_type);
    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding or missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `rb_gst_get_encoding_profile` seems to be

```
GstEncodingProfile *rb_gst_get_encoding_profile (const char *media_type);
```

but you assign its return value to a `gchar *`.

`GstEncodingProfile` is a `struct` type, as far as I can determine (`typedef struct _GstEncodingProfile GstEncodingProfile;`), and `gchar` is probably a `typedef` for a character type (most likely `typedef char   gchar;` from glib). So the types would be incompatible.